# Remove key from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have to remove all keys which are representing empty string for example

```
inventory = {"4"=>"", "1"=>"51059441", "3"=>""}
```

And The result should be

inventory = {"1"=>"51059441"}

Comment: test =  inventory.reject!{ |k| k == " "}

Answer (score 1):

Try [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-reject):

```
=> {"4"=>"", "1"=>"51059441", "3"=>""}.reject { |_, y| y.empty? }
#> {"1"=>"51059441"}
```

The same as `delete_if` but works on a copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Hash#delete_if`:

```
hash.delete_if {|k, v| !v.present? }
#=> {"1"=>"51059441"}
```

Note: `present?` is a Rails method. You can use `empty?` instead if you want delete only empty strings and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but a hash needs two parameters, the key and the value

```
inventory.reject{ |key, value| value == ""}
```

gives

```
{"1"=>"51059441"}
```